# Is a "data transfer type" the same as a "data transfer object"?

Tags: c#-3.0

In reading about C#, I have come across the terms "data transfer type" and "data transfer object".  This shows up around annonymous types, where a type is created on the fly to hold results, such as from LINQ.  Are these two terms referring to the same thing ?

Thanks,

Scott

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think some more context would help here.

An anonymous type has method scope.  So this means, it cannot be passed outside of it's method.  Whereas a Data Transfer Object entire purpose in life is to be passed outside of it's method.

I suspect their creating Data Transfer Types through an anonymous type and then projecting this to a Data Transfer Object.

But yeah, including the sentence you found this term in would help.

Comment: No, you got it for me, itchi.  I was wondering if that particular case of a DTO was just a wrapper for data with no behavior.  The scope (local, out of method, etc.), was something I hadn't considered.

Answer (score 0):

The type is the description of the object, it's class and it's methods/properties/variables/...

while the object is an instance of the type.

For example:

```
// this describes the type Foo
public sealed class Foo
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    /* ... */
}

// this is an object (instance) of foo
var fooInstance = new Foo() { ID = 4, };
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I know the difference between an object and a type.  I am wondering in this case if they are referring to an object that is data only for passing data.